# How can I get the bpf_helpers.h header file for my Linux kernel?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, header-files, bpf, ebpf

I am developing an eBPF program on an Ubuntu machine:

```
$ uname -a
Linux ubuntu-bionic 4.18.0-16-generic #17~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Tue Feb 12 13:35:51 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

To do this I need both `bpf.h` for a number of definitions as well [`bpf_helpers.h`](https://qmonnet.github.io/bpf-helpers/out/bpf-helpers.html) for helper function definitions. I installed a new kernel with the headers:

```
apt-get update -y
apt-get install -y linux-image-4.18.0-16-generic linux-headers-4.18.0-16-generic
```

The headers include `bpf.h`:

```
$ find /usr/src/linux-headers-4.18.0-16 -name bpf.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-4.18.0-16/include/uapi/linux/bpf.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-4.18.0-16/include/linux/bpf.h
```

but not `bpf_helpers.h`:

```
$ find /usr/src/linux-headers-4.18.0-16 -name bpf_helpers.h
```

How can I get this file for my kernel and why is it not included with the distribution headers?

I could checkout a particular version of the Linux kernel or get the file from [master](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/tools/testing/selftests/bpf/bpf_helpers.h) but the distribution could have potentially made changes to upstream which makes me uncomfortable doing this.

Comment: Had you consider looking within linux-source Ubuntu' package, i.e. your target OS kernel source package?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`bpf_helpers.h` is [not distributed with the kernel headers](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/search?q=filename%3Abpf_helpers.h&unscoped_q=filename%3Abpf_helpers.h), but with libbpf.

You can install libbpf on Ubuntu with:

```
apt install libbpf-dev
```

Or you can install it from the sources at https://github.com/libbpf/libbpf.

Comment: How could you tell that it is not distributed with the kernel headers? Your link just shows the file is in the particular location.

Comment: If it was distributed with the kernel headers, it would be in https://github.com/torvalds/linux/tree/master/include/uapi/linux, like `bpf.h`, `bpf_common.h` and `btf.h`.

Comment: After installation, you can include the bpf_helpers header file, for example, with `#include <bpf/bpf_helpers.h>` for C

Answer (score 2):

On Ubuntu I installed libbpf-dev to get that header:

```
sudo apt-get install libbpf-dev
```

```
$ apt-file list libbpf-dev | grep bpf_helpers.h
libbpf-dev: /usr/include/bpf/bpf_helpers.h
```

Comment: This basically just duplicates the accepted answer.

Comment: Look at the history of the accepted answer. I came up with this answer first. That answer originally just had "bpf_helpers.h is not distributed with the kernel headers..." The accepted answer just copied my answer afterwards.